# Dynamic pivoting in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, pivot

I have a scenario where I have to pivot a list of rows to columns dynamically .For a particular `order_number` there might be several `product`s. I want all those products to be in a separate column, along with its `product_id` (that too in columns), but we cannot predict how many products will there for a particular `order_number`.

Attaching a sample input table and desired output. I have tried the `crosstab` function but the result is not correct.

Table values:
[image]

Desired Ouput:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>*Contributions originally left as comments*</sub>

I typically aggregate dynamic columns into a single JSON value these days rather than creating dynamic columns for each attribute. That might be a challenge though as well, with your outdated (and unsupported) Postgres version - [a-horse-with-no-name](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1822/a-horse-with-no-name)

The desired output can't be obtained directly in SQL. You need to write a query that generates the query that generates your desired output. Giving up on your desired output and producing JSON instead may also be considered, as it would be simpler. - [Daniel Vérité](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/7119/daniel-v%C3%A9rit%C3%A9)

---